# FOSFacebookBundle does not call custom provider

Tags: facebook, symfony

I'm facing big issue while implementing FOSFacebookBundle.

I followed the docs and have following situation:
* when user clicks login a popup appears
* after user grants permission to the app, FB button is being changed (to Logout)

However, my custom provider is not called (only a constructor is called) - yes, I use a noobish debug method (creating empty files with the name of the class method :-)).

Anybody has any suggestion why? Any tips?

**Edit**
After some time of trying to solve that issue, I feel I'm lost.

Once again, here's my configuration:

app/config/config.yml:

```
fos_facebook:
    file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
    alias:  facebook
    app_id: xxx
    secret: xxx
    cookie: true
    permissions: [email, user_location]
```

app/config/routing.yml:

```
_security_login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Main:login }

_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Main:loginCheck }

_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Main:logout }
```

app/config/security.yml

```
security:
    factories:
        -"%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"
    providers:
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

        public:
            pattern:   ^/.*
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxx"
                server_url: "http://symfonytest.com.dev/app_dev.php/"
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
                default_target_path: /
            anonymous: true
            logout: true
```

I'm also implementing code into twig template as shown in docs (also implemented snippet from @Matt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same workflow as you and my custom user provider is called correctly and everything is working fine.

The first thing that you need to check is: do you have a JavaScript script that redirects the user to the `login_check` route after it has successfully login into Facebook via the popup? This is important because calling the `login_check` route after a valid authentication will trigger the security mechanism of Symfony2 that will call the FOSFacebookBundle special security code that will then call your own custom user provider. I think you may be just missing this small piece.

Here the pieces of JavaScript code required to make it work (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Core.facebookInitialize();
}); 

var Core = { 
    /**
     * Initialize facebook related things. This function will subscribe to the auth.login
     * facebook event. When the event is raised, the function will redirect the user to
     * the login check path.
     */
    facebookInitialize = function() {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
            Core.performLoginCheck();
        });
    };

    /**
     * Redirect user to the login check path.
     */
    performLoginCheck = function() {
        window.location = "http://localhost/app_dev.php/login_check";
    }
}
```

I put here my `security.yml` just to help you check for differences with your own file:

```
security:
    factories:
    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

  providers:
    acme.facebook_provider:
      # This is our custom user provider service id. It is defined in config.yml under services
      id: acme.user_provider

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    public:
      pattern:   ^/
      fos_facebook:
        app_url: "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID"
        server_url: "http://localhost/app_dev.php/"
        default_target_path: /
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login_check
        provider: acme.facebook_provider
      anonymous: true
      logout:    true
```

And my service definition for the custom user provider we use:

```
services:
  acme.user_provider:
    class: Application\AcmeBundle\Security\User\Provider\UserProvider
    arguments:
      facebook:      "@fos_facebook.api"
      entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
      validator:     "@validator"
```

You also need to create a new route for the `/login_check`, `/login` and `/logout` paths. Those route will be hooked by Symfony2 for the security process. Here an example of the implementation of the actions in a controller called `MainController` in my cases:

```
<?php

namespace Application\AcmeBundle\Controller;

use ...;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * This action is responsible of displaying the necessary informations for
     * a user to perform login. In our case, this will be a button to connect
     * to the facebook API.
     *
     * Important notice: This will be called ONLY when there is a problem with
     * the login_check or by providing the link directly to the user.
     *
     * @Route("/{_locale}/login", name = "_security_login", defaults = {"_locale" = "en"})
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        if ($this->request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $this->request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $this->request->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }
        return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Main:login.html.twig', array(
            'error' => $error
        ));
    }

    /**
     * This action is responsible of checking if the credentials of the user
     * are valid. This will not be called because this will be intercepted by the
     * security component of Symfony.
     *
     * @Route("/{_locale}/login_check", name = "_security_check", defaults = {"_locale" = "en"})
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
        // Call intercepted by the Security Component of Symfony
    }

    /**
     * This action is responsible of login out a user from the site. This will
     * not be called because this will be intercepted by the security component
     * of Symfony.
     *
     * @Route("/{_locale}/logout", name = "_security_logout", defaults = {"_locale" = "en"})
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        return $this->redirect('index');
    }
}
```

Hope this help, if you have more questions or I misunderstand something from your problem, don't hesitate to leave a comment.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've implemented the code from your answer, including Javascript without any luck :( Still the same situation happens. Any help appreciated!

Comment: BTW, I'm also available to get the user object from the Graph API in the constructor of my provider. I've lost my hope :)

Comment: Weird, cookie `fbsr_195918313779380` is being created.

Comment: After some debugging I decided to delete this cookie. After authorization the app with Facebook (via popup), I'm redirected to /login_check route and I'm getting an exception: `Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?`. Help? :)

Comment: Discovered really weird situation. Same as above, after logging with Facebook I'm being redirected to the /login_check route, BUT when I try to log user created with FOSUserBundle my... Facebook custom provider is being called (which is weird imo).

Comment: Since the cookie is created, you are on the right direction. The current version of the FOSFacebookBundle use the new oauth 2.0 authentication scheme. This is where the cookie comes from. I'm gonna edit my answer to help you with the controller part.

Comment: Can't find the words to thank you. Really. I've edited my answer. After implementing the controller part, I deleted all cookies, hit "Login" button and faced this error `The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?`. Once again, thanks in helping me solve that issue! Appreciated!

Comment: I've read Symfony docs twice today, especially routing and security. I understand everything (I think so) but I really don't know why I cannot implement this bundle successfully. My configuration seems to be correct, I think.

Comment: Edited my question, pasted configuration, if you can take a look, I'll be delighted.

Comment: Interesting stuff: I presumed (and even find a note in the controller from you) that /login_check call should be intercepted by the Security Component but it isn't (getting `The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?` error). Weird.

Comment: I think you may have some problem with your firewalls. You see, you defining two firewalls (three to be exact but the dev one is not revelant). The firewall `main` has a pattern matching `^/` and the firewall `public` has a pattern `^/.*`. However, both patterns match the same set of strings (in fact, `^/` is equivalent to `^/.*`). In this case, order matters so try putting the `public` one before the `main` one for testing purpose just to see if it will be intercepted.

Comment: Moreover, I don't think both firewall should have the same login routes. Maybe you should isolate one form each other (i.e. having something like `/form/login` for FOSUserBundle and `/facebook/login` for FOSFacebookBundle. I would try also without the `main` firewall just to see if it is an interferrence between the two bundles.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3065/discussion-between-matt-and-users1184848)