# Facebook + UserBundle authentication with symfony2

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

I'm trying to authenticate my users via facebook or userbundle on symfony2

Here's what I did so far (and it works, although not as I want):

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: .*
        fos_facebook:
            app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/appName/"
            server_url: "http://localhost/facebookApp/"
            login_path: /fblogin
            check_path: /fblogin_check
            default_target_path: /
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
```

The problem with that config is that when the user is not logged in, he's redirected to /login (form_login), while I'd like him to be redirected to Facebook authentication by default

I already tried simply removing the form_login, but then if I access /login (which is how I want users to login outside facebook), it doesn't know the /login_check route to submit the login form

Maybe chain_provider would be a solution? I didn't get it working either

Comment: +1. I've had this issue as well; would love to see a good solution to it.

Comment: Does this solution assist in any way -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257183/fosfacebookbundle-does-not-call-custom-provider

Answer (score 1):

An easy and mabye more usable option would be to show all the login options in the login page (including facebook, twitter, open id, or whatever you'd like to use)

Answer (score 1):

Chain providers is indeed the solution to this problem. Here is what you security.yml config shoud look like:

```
providers:
  my_project.chain_provider:
    chain:
      providers: [fos_userbundle, my_project.facebook_provider]
  fos_userbundle:
    id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
  my_project.facebook_provider:
    id: my_project.user_provider.facebook
```

And, of course, you need to define your own facebook provider as stated [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-integration-with-fosuserbundle.md)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the fos_userbundle provider for the form_login (and keep the rest of the configuration):

```
form_login:
    provider: fos_userbundle
```

I didn't dig too much, but I think Symfony2 is automatically creating a chained provider in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can write your [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) where you will be looking whether a user goes to /login form directly or by redirecting.